# How can you figure out the name of an object if you know what it's property is equal to?

Tags: javascript, object

I am working on a JavaScript program that helps you encrypt and decrypt messages. In order to make it very secure, I am planning on creating an object that contains the properties of `id` and `text`. Here is an example object:

```
var object1 = {
    id: "AE309JKL36784AJBCMDH"
    text: "∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚"
}
```

Let's say I know that text is equal to `∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚`. How am I able to figure out that the name of the object that has this value for the property of `text` is `object1`?

Thank in advance.

Comment: `Object.keys(window).find(k => Object.values(window[k]).includes("your text"))`

Comment: Why do you need to know the name of  the object's reference? That smells like you actually want it indexed in a different way.

Comment: Stackoverflow gets quite a few questions like this. They are almost all certainly [xy problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you could describe your use case and why you think the names of variable will be significant to your goal. My guess is that you almost always be better off with a real data structure like an array or object rather than depending on finding the names of variables that point to objects.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly. I need the name of the object so I can figure out the other property "id". If I know the name, then I can simply do: var id = object1.id

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the `scope`, where you declare your `var`, so I would rather use `this` (which will also work for `window` case):

```
var object1 = {
  id:  "AE309JKL36784AJBCMDH",
  text: "∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚"
};

console.log(Object.keys(this).find(k => this[k] && this[k].text && this[k].text === '∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚'));
```

@Dave Newton is absolutely right, this answer will not work for example in this case:

```
(function(){
  var object1 = {
    id:  "AE309JKL36784AJBCMDH",
    text: "∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚"
  };

  console.log(Object.keys(this).find(k => this[k] && this[k].text &&     this[k].text === '∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚'));
}())
```

where `this` will be calling scope `window`

Comment: Using this makes it depend on the context you're calling it *from*, which seems even worse.

Answer (score -2):

```
Object.keys(window).find((key) => {
    let obj = window[key];
    return obj && typeof obj === "object" && obj.text && obj.id && obj.text === "∆∂˙˚∆ƒ˙ø©ˆ´¨¬˚å˙∂©¬˚";
});
```